# How to create a "virtual device environment" in Java to work with multiple monitors?

Tags: java

The method getScreenDevices() of GraphicsEnvironment must return a list of GraphicsDevice in my system. How can I configure my system to work with these GraphicsDevice, beforehand?

Comment: This is a very poorly-worded question.  Could you offer more details about what you're trying to do so that we know what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have the monitors hooked up and enabled in the operating system, Java will detect them.  Consider this code:

```
GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
GraphicsDevice[] devices = env.getScreenDevices();
Rectangle[] screenBounds = new Rectangle[devices.length];
for (int x = 0; x < this.devices.length; x++) {
  GraphicsConfiguration conf = this.devices[x].getDefaultConfiguration();
  screenBounds[x] = conf.getBounds();
}
```

You can also investigate `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenInsets(configuration)` to get a list of insets so you know, for example, where the start bar is.

Be warned, however, that if you try to do this under certain X windows environments, the insets are not available.  I worked around this problem by creating an invisible frame on each screen, maximizing them, waiting for them to generate a resize event, and then grabbing their bounds and disposing of them.  But I only trigger this code if I get zero insets from all the monitors.

Comment: I think he wants to create his own Device for tests.

Comment: I agree, but he speaks about "Virtual device", so I'm not really sure.

Comment: If you're going to be dealing with multiple monitors, a good plan is to probe the monitors of the system once at the beginning.  Then, you cache the results and anytime you need to check the monitor dimensions, you check your cached results.  This way you're not continually probing the hardware, which I know from experience fails intermittently on some X windows systems.

Comment: To restore my deleted comment - if you want to test software that works with multiple monitors, you're going to need a system that has multiple monitors.  The only other possible way would be to take the caching approach that I just mentioned, except create two virtual monitors in your cache.  If all of your code interacts with your cache, you'll be able to simulate the multiple monitors that way and know that it will work once there are actually multiple monitors.

Comment: Unfortunately, the traditional maximize buttons won't honor that kind of setup.  Of course, I have found problems with maximizing windows programmatically on some X windows setups.  It turns out that if you want to break into this stuff and start to effect the behavior, you'll end up rewriting a lot of things to make them work how you want.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well your question, and you want to create a "virtual device" here is an answer :

As the GraphicsEnvironment uses system properties to access the available devices, you would have to modify your JVM or trick the system to make it thinks it has another device.

Comment: Even if you created these devices, how would you be able to test with them?  Nothing you created on those devices would be visible!

Comment: I guess those virtual devices could be linked latter to other remote devices.

Comment: How could that be done?  I've never seen a remote device interface, and there are no details about how to create it.  How do you modify the JVM or trick the system?

Comment: For the JVM modification I would change the way the devices are detected to add my own layer. And for the system, I would have to write a kernel module. I didn't said it was trivial, I said it was possible.